# Show that $ T_f(\varphi):=\int f \varphi d x, \quad \varphi \in \mathcal{S} $ is a tempered distribution.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let $f$ be in $ L_{\text {loc }}^1$, and suppose that there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $f / p$ is integrable on $\mathbf{R}$. Show that
$$
T_f(\varphi):=\int f \varphi d x, \quad \varphi \in \mathcal{S}
$$
is a tempered distribution.

My attempt: Suppose that $p$ is a polynomial of degree $k$

$| \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \varphi(x) dx | \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)/p(x)| |p(x)\varphi(x)| dx \leq C \mathcal{N}_{0, k} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |p(x) \phi(x)|dx \leq + \infty $ by hypothesis.

Comment: You want the last inequality to just be $< +\infty$; to justify this, note that since $\varphi$ is Schwartz you have $|\varphi(x)| \leq C(1+x^2)^{-k-1}$ for some constant $C>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof should be:

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\varphi(x)dx\right| &\leqslant 
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}\right||p(x)\varphi(x)|dx \\&\leqslant \sup|p(x)\varphi(x)|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}\right|dx
\\&=C\sup|p(x)\varphi(x)|
\end{align*}

This means that $T_{f}(\varphi)$ is tempered distribution.